# Using "into": Tuesday into Thursday

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of *into* in the following sentence:

"Residents of southern Japan and South Korea are being put on alert for strengthening Typhoon Soulik to pose serious threats to lives and property Tuesday **into** Thursday."

Comment: The time period being discussed started Tuesday and lasted through part of Thursday.

Comment: Does that mean that the threat might start within this period of time and that it might go on for longer, even after Thursday?

Comment: @piti: It could, but the sentence makes no prediction beyond Thursday.

Answer (score 1):

**into** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/98530?rskey=hurjtq&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> 11. Introducing a period of time to the midst of which anything advances or continues.

As in:

... to lives and property Tuesday into Thursday." (your question)

and another:

The drizzling rain continued far into the following night.